# getting this { "timestamp": "2022-10-19T08:57:38.327+00:00", "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error", "path": "/courses/420" }

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

All looks fine [image]

MyController Code ..

```
package com.springrest.springrest.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springrest.springrest.entities.Course;
import com.springrest.springrest.services.CourseService;

@RestController    //This will tell spring boot that this is the Controller whenever we send a request by GET method in POSTMAN, to identify where the Controller is located 
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/home")    // This is necessary in order to map with controller whenever we call by GET method in POSTMAN home method will be called.
    public String home() {
        return "Welcome to home page";
        
    }
    `enter code here`@Autowired     // we don't need to create object Springboot will automatically create an object for us
    private CourseService courseService; // a variable must be created same as service package parent class of CourseServiceImpl i.e CourseService
    
    //Get all the courese 
    // this getCourses will return List of courses 
    @GetMapping("/courses")
    public List<Course> getCourses(){           //the Course is defined in entities package 
        return courseService.getCourses();   // courseService will call getCourses method from CourseService Class but it us abstract so It will go to CourseServiceImpl list will be returned by getCourse but implemented in Constructor
    }
    
    //get course by id
    // this getCourse will return one course 
    @GetMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
    public Course getCourse(@PathVariable String courseId) {
        return this.courseService.getCourse(Long.parseLong(courseId));
    }
    @PostMapping("/courses")    // 
    public Course addCourse(@RequestBody Course course) {
        return this.courseService.addCourse(course);
    }
    //Update the course using  PUT request
    @PutMapping("/courses") 
    //@Autowired  
    public Course updateCourse(@RequestBody Course course){
        return this.courseService.updateCourse(course);
    }
    
    // DELETE method delete the course  
    
    @DeleteMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
    
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteCourse(@PathVariable String CourseId) {
        try {
            this.courseService.deleteCourse(Long.parseLong(CourseId));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

CourseService code...

```
package com.springrest.springrest.services;

import java.util.List;

import com.springrest.springrest.entities.Course;

public interface CourseService {
    public List<Course> getCourses();   // Because its a abstract class therefore it don't have body
    public Course getCourse(long courseId);
    public Course addCourse(Course course);
    public Course updateCourse(Course course);
    public void deleteCourse(long parseLong);
 }
```

CourseServiceImpl..

```
 package com.springrest.springrest.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.springrest.springrest.entities.Course;
@Service
public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService {
    
    List<Course>  list;

    public CourseServiceImpl() {
        
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Course(145,"Java Core Course "," This course contains basics of Core Java "));
        list.add(new Course(420,"Spring boot Course", "Creating REST API using Spring boot"));
        list.add(new Course(110, "Python Course","This is Python course for beginners"));
        list.add(new Course(220, "Angular JS Course","This is Angular JS course for beginners"));
        list.add(new Course(330, "React JS Course","This is React JS course for beginners"));

    }
   @Override
    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Course getCourse(long courseId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Course c= null;
        for(Course course:list) {
            if(course.getId()==courseId) {
                c= course; 
                break;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public Course addCourse(Course course) {
        list.add(course);
        return course;
    }

    
     @Override
    public Course updateCourse(Course course) {
        list.forEach(e -> {
            if(e.getId()==course.getId()) {
                e.setTitle(course.getTitle());
                e.setDescription(course.getDescription());
            }
        });
        return course;
    }
     @Override
   
    public void deleteCourse(long parseLong) {
        list= this.list.stream().filter(e -> e.getId()!=parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I am new Learning REST API I have created Controller Class, Service Class, Implementation Class But When I run PUTMAPPING or DeleteMapping It Shows Given error( POSTMAN Screentshot Given )
I don't know where the Problem is I have given The problem in Header Section POSTMAN Screen Shot and all class Screen Shot I have attaeched in Imagag section Kindly Rectify This.

Comment: Since you are getting an http 500, you should have the error with stack trace in the server log. Please provide this.

Comment: How to Provide stack trace in the server log?

Comment: Looks like you are running your project from your IDE (IntelliJ?) so you will see it in the run (or debug) console there. It i the window on the bottom right on your first screenshot.

Comment: `WARN` and `org.springfr...MissingPathVariab..` is far from "all looks fine" ;) (and that is where "console" and server.log ...please prefer text to images where possible;)

Comment: grekier I am using SpringToolSuit(STS)